Confused about the right sequence or order of receiver DSP functions
I am looking for a  simple answer for a question (or questions) which may be  complex ( I tried  to answer this question by reading Michael's Rice book on digital communications , and I still couldn't figure it out)
Suppose we receive a, say QAM signal, affected by channel multipath, i.e. carrying InterSymbol Interference and suppose the reception is not data aided, can in this case clock (or timing), phase  and frequency error correction take place before equalization? and what should take place first, i.e. the order of the sequence? Won't ISI affect these functions if done before equalization? and suppose now that the reception is data aided , how would this change things?
Thank you

Read the first paragraph: Uff, if you have the full Rice in you, then it's probably not an easy question at all!

I believe that if someone masters a certain subject, then he can always give a simple explanation which may not go into details, but will at least help a little bit. A little bit is always better than nothing

I think you're complimenting my answer? Thanks!

There's different equalizers and different phase, timing and frequency recovery method, and the order depends on which ones you use.
For example, a decision feedback equalizer necessary happens after the timing recovery; a blind feed-forward equalizer typically before. Whether you need one or the other, or both, depends on your specific channel, how fast it changes, and what data rate you need to achieve.
Same for timing recovery and phase recovery: a Costas-style loop (even thrown at 16 QAM or higher, you can act as if symbols that aren't on the main diagonals are simply noisy; assuming symmetrically probable symbols, and usually they are even equally probable, that is zero-mean noise) will want to be applied after timing recovery, but a preamble detector might not.
So, I guess, the answer to your question is: "It depends, and you need to read the chapters on the individual types of equalizers and synchronizers in detail".

Here is another answer I received, any comments? Q:  1-As you can imagine, you cannot measure or synch to phase unless you have resolved timing.
2-similarly you can’t resolve phase unless you have canceled frequency offset.
3-and finally you can't resolve channel, (equalization) till you have resolved timing and phase.
the equalizer is an adaptive filter that is convinced it can fix all the problems in the received signal. you must not let the equalizer have free reign. It must be at the end of the processing chain. I manage to do that by reducing its convergence rate, by small mu.UQ

no, I don't have comments on an answer without a source, sorry! Especially not if its in conflict with mine, and you could prove them wrong by looking up the things I mention in my answer ;) I'm happy to help you when you ask specific questions, though :)

I was hoping for a comment regarding the last paragraph:

Quote  the equalizer is an adaptive filter that is convinced it can fix all the problems in the received signal. you must not let the equalizer have free reign  Unquote

that is a vague statement that in my opinion is overly general, without a lot of context. It makes absolutely no sense to ask for comments on excerpts from other people, who you don't even quote correctly.

So is there at least an agreement with that comment : That the equalizer can theoretically at least replace timing and phase recovery ( I include frequency error in phase) ?

that is a misinterpretation of what has been written by me and the other source that you're still not quoting correctly.

No problem. Thank you
